# Delay execution of JavaScript function after the one before is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my page when creating a product successfully with a form, which uses a modal box, the modal goes away with an effect and then the page with the list of products should be "refreshed" with the new added item.

However, the going away effect the modal does kind of destroys the flow of the animation because the list of items is loaded too soon.

I don't want to throw a random number delay. I want to execute the function that loads the items right after the animation is finished.

How can I do this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#create-battery', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('/battery', $('#create-battery-form').serialize(), function(data) {
        if (data['status'] == true) {
            $('#errors').addClass('hidden');
            $('#success').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#success').html(data['message']);
            $('#add-new-battery').modal('hide'); // here is the hide effect
            renderBatteries(); // here is where all the products are loaded again in the list
        } else {
            $('#success').addClass('hidden');
            $('#errors').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#errors').html(data['errors']);
            $('#errors').addClass('top-buffer');
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Now when my `renderBatteries()` function is called the items are rendered. But the way this function is made it makes my notice messages go away:

```
function renderBatteries(url, notice) {
    if (url === undefined || url === null) url = '/battery/all';
    $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#content').empty();
            $('#content').append(data['view']);
            if (data['empty']) {
                $('#batteries-list').empty();
                $('#content').append('<div class="alert alert-info top-buffer col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">No batteries found in the database.</div>');
            }
        });
}
```

I tried fixing it adding this last line:

```
if (notice) {
    $('#success').html(notice);
}
```

However the notice appears for a short instant and then goes away. Why is this happening, if I am doing this **after** emptying the content?

Here's how it looks like:

```
function renderBatteries(url, notice) {
    if (url === undefined || url === null) url = '/battery/all';
    $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#content').empty();
            $('#content').append(data['view']);
            if (data['empty']) {
                $('#batteries-list').empty();
                $('#content').append('<div class="alert alert-info top-buffer col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">No batteries found in the database.</div>');
            }
            if (notice) {
                $('#success').html(notice);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modals?

Comment: yes I am using Bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an event that is fired when the modal has finished being hidden. Create a listener that calls your function:

```
$('#add-new-battery').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  renderBatteries();
});
```

Check "events" here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Comment: ok now that works but I am having a problem with notices. Can you take a look to my update?

Comment: Is `#success` a descendant of `#content`?

Comment: My guess is that due to the nature of the asynchronous call of `renderBatteries`, the `$('#content').empty()` is being called AFTER you show the notice

Comment: What can I do to ensure that the notice renders after the `#content` is emptied?

Comment: Create your notice at the very end of `$.get` in `renderBatteries`

Comment: That is what I was doing and the notice is still going away

Comment: Are you sure it's at the end of `$.get` callback and NOT and the end of the `renderBatteries` function?